# ng repeat alter with media queries and screen size

Tags: javascript, angularjs, responsive-design

I have a JSon file that is meant to resemble that of a Youtube collection of info.
As such there are several img urls of varying sizes.
I'm currently listing the images in my html using an ng-repeat and directing to a specific image size.

What would be the recommended method to alter the path of this ng-repeat depending upon the screen size (media queries)

```
         <div class="video-list">
          <div class="scrollbar scroll-y">
              <div data-ng-repeat="video in videos"class="list-items">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#" data-ng-click="setVideo(video.snippet.resourceId.videoId, video.snippet.title, video.snippet.description)">
                    <img src="[[video.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url]]"/>
                    <h3><span>[[video.snippet.title| removeBrackets]]</span></h3>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

but i would like it to display [[video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url]] when the screen is at a specific size. I understand I'll probably need to make a filter or a function. I'm far too new to angular and javascript to understand the best practice.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You could try applying a percent width of the images and/or incorporate a responsive design such as twitter bootstrap.

Comment: I do wonder why i don't think of things like this first! Thanks, i'll have a play around :D

Comment: You could have multiple links on the page and hide the ones which do not pertain to the screen size you want.